# magento sort filter options by position

Tags: magento

I'm looking for a way to change the default ordering of Attribute options in Magento. When you print out the filter options from an attribute, it always displays in alphabetical order, not the defined 'position' setting in the admin.

I'd like to be able to change the default sorting for filter options by position, then by name.

I've seen a couple of similar questions on stack overflow - but neither of these options worked in our EE 1.11.2.0 version.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change it sorting option through coding then go to the app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Product/Collection.php and open addAttributeToSort function here you can define your sorting option